# Quando é criado um sistema operacional os compiladores de ASM, linguagem C, CPP devem ser criados também ou são portáveis?

Tags: c, c++, assembly, sistema-operacional, compiladores

#### 1 - AHTAH! Mais um maluco querendo refundar a Microsoft - Porque essa me$#%%$#$ de  pergunta?

Para dar um pouco de contexto a minha dúvida: sempre programei em linguagens de alto nível, para resolver questões administrativas, gerenciais e naturalmente resolver algum anseio de usuários e administradores de empresa, mas, nunca deixei de cavocar os bits, pegar posicionamento de mouse com PEEK no BASIC, fazer linguagem interpretada no Clipper, futricar em EXE de outros no PCTools, essas coisas de gente curiosa.

#### 2 - Motivos (pessoais, quem sabe)

De um tempo pra cá tenho vontade de baixar o nível e tenho dúvidas sobre o que é possível na escovação de bits. Pensando em sistemas operacionais, naturalmente no âmbito educacional e de aprendizagem, me questiono sobre como fazer a base de um SO de maneira que consiga suportar os compiladores existentes (desde ASM até C, CPP e até mais alto nível como Pascal e etc).

#### 3 - Mas, qual a dúvida?

Preciso criar um Assembly compatível com meu SO? Ou o NASM da vida vai rodar naturalmente lá? (Se sim, ufa) (Se não, o que fazer?)

#### 4 - Mas, ainda tem mais

Depois de ter um ASM rodando, conseguiria compilar um GCC por exemplo?

#### 5 - E vamos além

Para compatibilização, posso usar sistemas de arquivos existentes FAT32, NTFS e etc, nesse "pseudoSO"? Pensando nessa dúvida me veio um questionamento do tipo:, quem vem antes, o ovo ou a galinha? Pois, se o sistema de arquivos é feito em C ou CPP, como pode o CPP estar legível em uma mídia? (brincadeirinha)

Comment: Como a conversa ficou extensa, foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101455/discussion-on-question-by-valmor-flores-quando-e-criado-um-sistema-operacional-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta parte de algumas premissas erradas.

Nenhum sistema operacional precisa fazer nada que ele não queira. O motivo de criar um não importando o propósito é pode fazer o que o criador deseja e deixar de lado o que ele não deseja, para atender seus objetivos.

Não existe isso de "são portáveis", esse conceito não cabe neste contexto, pelo menos não dessa forma. Portabilidade é algo que se faz, não existe nada inerente. Portabilidade não é algo natural, é construído, então a resposta é que não precisam ser criados, mas podem, depende do seu objetivo.

Aí tem outra premissa errada porque não existem compiladores ASM, e os compiladores de C ou C++ existem prontos e podem ser usados no seu sistema operacional fazendo **diversas** adaptações, ou você pode criar um compilador seu. Se for fazer um sistema operacional, compilador, tudo, boa sorte. Se for adaptar compiladores para seu sistema operacional que seja tão diferente, boa sorte. Se for fazer seu sistema operacional ser compatível com o que existe pronto para não ter que adaptar muito, boa sorte.

O problema hoje sempre é a interoperabilidade. É difícil falar se vale a pena, mas para quem não tem muitos recursos em geral não vale. É muito mais fácil fazer algo isolado, porém pela falta de recursos será limitado. Só existe uma solução para ter algo completo interoperando ou fazer tudo do zero, ter muitos recursos. E por recursos entenda de várias maneiras, não estou falando só de dinheiro.

Assembly é uma linguagem então não tem que criar nada nesse sentido, Assembly já existe e é universal porque é uma especificação. Assembler é um montador para lidar com Assembly, então você não precisa criar, mas pode se for seu objetivo fazer isto, um sistema operacional e um Assembler são coisas ortogonais.

Não precisa de um Assembler no seu sistema operacional para rodar o GCC, precisa adaptar o GCC para funcionar no seu sistema operacional. Ou fazer seus sistema operacional de uma forma que ele seja 100% compatível com a forma que o GCC trabalha hoje pronto. Boa sorte.

Pode usar o sistema de arquivos que quiser, a não ser que algum tenha alguma restrição legal, mas em geral isso não existe. Por usar entenda que você tem que reproduzir no seu sistema tudo o que eles fazem em outros sistemas.

Não sei o que a última dúvida quer dizer, mas não vejo dicotomia alguma na ideia. Tudo o que for fazer neste SO será inicialmente feito fora dele e não nele, e aí transportado para ele. Talvez o "segredo" que quer saber seja esse.

Não existe pseudo SO, ou é um SO ou não é, independente dele ser comercial, útil, universal ou como queira categorizar.

O fato é que tudo isso é tão mais complexo do que está tratado aqui...

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição. Vamos ver se eu entendi. Se eu desejar criar um SO que seja compatível com GCC então, tenho que oferecer a ele, tudo que hoje ele espera de um SO, baseado em um que exista, claro "Linux" por exemplo. Passo número 1 de um SO seria este nível de compatibilização. 
Me referi a pseudoSO por ele não existir. O correto até seria imaginarioSO kk

Comment: O começo está certo, depois não necessariamente. Eu já pensei em fazer um SO, mas eu jamais tentaria trazer as ferramentas existentes pra rodar no meu SO. Isso beira a insanidade fazer sozinho. Pode ser em uma equipe de tamanho razoável com vários profissionais capacitados em disciplinas diferentes. Ou se for um super gênio da computação (nunca vi um tão grande). Sem equipe boa hoje é muito complicado tentar um SO que execute quase tudo o que existe por aí. Vai dar uma olhada no fonte do GCC tudo que precisa mexer. E não ache que vão deixar você fazer isso lá, será um fork só seu.

Comment: Coisas imaginárias tudo pode, e são fáceis "de fazer".

Comment: Sem dúvida, fazer um SO hoje, que seja compatível com GCC por exemplo, como você falou, seria praticamente impossível, visto o tanto de coisas existentes. Só em termos de hardware já deixa qualquer um bugado. E, aprender sobre tudo requer anos luz de estudo e sanidade mental. Mas, brincar com isso é legal e andei olhando alguns SOs simplistas que fazem o básico e é legal. Dureza é que o dia a dia não deixa muito tempo pra explorar mais sobre essas coisas. Queria saber se pegar o mikeOS, por exemplo, e fazer um C ou C++ rodar dentro dele seria algo muito difícil.